# I am trying to read video from opencv but i got error every time i use cv2.imshow or imread

Tags: python, opencv

this is the code i use

```
cap =  cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')
while True:
    _,img= cap.read()
    image=cv2.resize(img,(32,32))
    cv2.imshow('video',image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and I got this error
'OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-1drr4hl0\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:651: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage' '

Comment: Did you try to "Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support"?

Comment: Yes I tried to rebuild it but it keep giving the same error

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem while using cv2 on Anaconda3 Jupyter Notebook.

**Solution:** pip install opencv-contrib-python

If error occurs run cmd as administrator